# linux how to find out which program connect to remote port

Tags: linux, shell

See the output below:

```
tcp   0   0   192.168.2.222:35774   192.168.3.200:9090   TIME_WAIT
```

On  Linux I want to find out which program connects to  192.168.3.200:9090, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
# lsof -Pnl +M -i4 // Listens on all IPV4 Ports
```

or

```
# netstat -ntp
```

are the commands you are searching for.

Then try to use fgrep to find the line. (in your case: fgrep '192.168.3.200:9090')

--> `netstat -ntp | fgrep '192.168.3.200:9090'`

Answer (score 0):

you can do `netstat -anp`.
You'll need to `sudo` or be root to see the process information.

```
tcp   0   0   0.0.0.0:22   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   665/sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -avnp | egrep '^tcp' | fgrep '192.168.3.200:9090'
```

Comment: thanks for reply, see below
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.250:10050         192.168.2.90:43288          TIME_WAIT   -
what dose '-' mean ?

Comment: @mk2011 - you don't own the process and are not root to see the process details